# Static files are not being served with gin's Grouping routes

Tags: html, go, go-gin

I am trying to serve CSS, JS files but they are not being loaded and it gives 404 status error for each static file except HTMLs. Here is the code

```
func main() {
router := gin.Default()
router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*.html")

router.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./web", true)))

// Simple group: v1
v1 := router.Group("/v1")
{
    //v1.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./web", true))) this didn't make it work either 

    v1.GET("/login", getlogin)
    v1.POST("/checkAuthLog", postRegis)
}

// Simple group: v2
v2 := router.Group("/v2")
{
    v2.GET("/login", getlogin)
    v2.POST("/checkAuthLog", postRegis)
}

router.Run(":8080")
```

}

Normally, without group routing it works fine. But this way, it didn't work no matter how much i tried.

When i check source code of HTML via browser, it links to :

> http://localhost:8080/v1/css/style.css

Though, it should be http://localhost:8080/css/style.css.  Somehow it is looking at v1 path for css file. Also, In HTML file  it links to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

I couldn't find where i am wrong.

By the way project structure is like:

```
-main.go
-templates
----index.html
----login.html 
-web
----css
----fonts
----js
----img
```

As i mentioned, normally it works when i just type /login but things get messy when it starts with  v1/login path.

Lastly here is GIN framework log.

[GIN] 2021/12/08 - 18:13:50 | ***200*** |      6.7847ms |             ::1 | GET      "/v1/login"

[GIN] 2021/12/08 - 18:13:50 | **404** |            0s |             ::1 | GET      "/v1/css/bootstrap.min.css"

[GIN] 2021/12/08 - 18:13:50 | **404** |            0s |             ::1 | GET      "/v1/css/style.css"

[GIN] 2021/12/08 - 18:13:50 | **404** |            0s |             ::1 | GET      "/v1/js/script.js"

[GIN] 2021/12/08 - 18:13:50 | **404** |            0s |             ::1 | GET      "/v1/js/bootstrap.min.js"

[GIN] 2021/12/08 - 18:13:50 | **404** |            0s |             ::1 | GET      "/v1/js/script.js"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem can usually be fixed by having `href`, `src`, etc. be an absolute path, instead of relative. e.g. `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: OMG it really worked.  I didn't know what forward slash is for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that this is simply how browsers resolve paths they find in the HTML. If they find a relative path then they will *append* it to the current page's URL path. If they find an absolute path then they will use that as the current page's URL full path. e.g. if you load the html on `/foo/bar/baz/` and it contains `href="styles.css"` then the browser will request `/foo/bar/baz/styles.css`, but if the html contains `href="/styles.css` the browser will request `/styles.css`.